# Using mosaic in r to merge multiple geotiff

Tags: r, r-raster, geotiff

I have 50 geotiff files in the same folder.
All of them represent elevation data in different parts of the world.
I would like to merge certain geotiff files, and I found `mosaic` in R might help us.
I have moved those geotiff into the same folder, and I wrote a R script show below:

```
setwd()
a<-list.files(pattern="*.tiff",file.name=TRUE)
combind<-merge(a,fun=mean)
```

However, this script returned an error:
error in as.data.frame(y)

May I ask how could I improve my script?

Comment: You may need `do.call(merge, a)` and there is no `fun` argument for `merge`

Comment: @akrun
Thank you for kindly reply, but it returns "second argument must be a list".

Comment: You didn't provide an example.  It could be `Reduce(function(...) merge(...),  a)`

Comment: by the way, the "merge" is from the package "raster".

Comment: You need to give a reproducible example

Comment: If you check the `?merge` from `raster`, the example does work with `do.call(merge, x)` and there also I don't find any `fun` argument

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Edit 2023-06: use `terra::vrt()` or `terra::mosaic()`

Since `gdalUtils` seems unmaintained for a while now, you can use a similar approach as in my original answer just using the more up-to-date `terra` package which is the successor to the `raster` package:

```
library(terra)

vrt(
  x = list.files(path = "folder/to/images", pattern = "*.tif$", full.names = TRUE), 
  filename = "dem.vrt"
)
# afterwards read it as if it was a normal raster:
dem <- rast("dem.vrt")
```

Another possibility is to use `terra::mosaic()`. This gives you more control over the aggregation function in overlapping pixels. For that you first create a raster collection using `sprc()` from a list of `rast` objects and then `mosaic` to combine them into one raster.

```
library(terra)
# vector of file names
fls <- list.files("your/folder", ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)
# list of rast objects
r_lst <- lapply(fls, rast)
# create spatial raster collection
coll <- sprc(r_list)

# combine all rasters
mosaic(coll, function = "mean")
```

### Original answer using `gdalUtils`

You can make use of the powerful `GDAL` functions. From my experience these are much faster than pure R code.

My approach would be with `library(gdalUtils)`:

First, build a virtual raster file ([vrt](http://gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html)):

```
library(gdalUtils)
setwd(...)
gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = "*.tif", # uses all tiffs in the current folder
             output.vrt = "dem.vrt")
```

Then, copy the virtual raster to a actual physical file:

```
gdal_translate(src_dataset = "dem.vrt", 
               dst_dataset = "dem.tif", 
               output_Raster = TRUE # returns the raster as Raster*Object
                                    # if TRUE, you should consider to assign 
                                    # the whole function to an object like dem <- gddal_tr..
               options = c("BIGTIFF=YES", "COMPRESSION=LZW"))
```

Another pure (and probably **slower**) `raster` package solution would be:

```
f <- list.files(path = "your/path", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)
rl <- lapply(f, raster)

do.call(merge, c(rl, tolerance = 1))
```

you have to adjust the `tolerance` since the raster files will probably not have the same origin.

Comment: Thank you for kindly reply.
The gdalUtils finally return warning message ""C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdal_translate.exe" -of "GTiff" "dem.vrt" "elevation.tif"' had status 1.
Therefore, I am trying the second code.

Comment: Perhaps you have to set `options = c("BIGTIFF=YES")`

Comment: I had the time to check. In my case `gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = ".tif$" ...)` failed. I edited my answer. Perhapy you might check. Just substitute `".tif$"` with `".tif"`. I also added some options.